STM32, arm-none-eabi: String is not output with printf if the string contains a leading `\n`
In my STM32 application I have the following code in main:
printf("\nRunning Smoke Tests...\n");
The problem is that the whole string is not sent via UART. With some testing I found out that the leading \n is the cause. If i remove the leading \n the string is sent without issues via UART.
This is the implementation of _write which is used by printf:
int _write(int file, char* ptr, uint16_t len)
{
    UNUSED(file);

    // Calculate minimum transmission time in milliseconds with a safety margin of 10
    static constexpr uint32_t BAUD_RATE = 115200; // Baud rate in bits per second - see MX_USART2_UART_Init()
    static constexpr uint32_t BITS_PER_CHARACTER = 10; // 1 start bit, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity - see MX_USART2_UART_Init()
    auto const timeout_ms =
        static_cast<uint32_t>((static_cast<double>(len * BITS_PER_CHARACTER) * 1000.0 / BAUD_RATE) * 10);

    auto aux_result = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(ptr), len, timeout_ms);
    if (aux_result == 0) {
        return len; // transmit succeeded, return length of transmitted data
    } else {
        return -1; // transmit failed, return error
    }
}

The debugger gives some insight:
This is the Stacktrace:
stm32-template-project.elf  
    Thread #1 (Suspended : Breakpoint)  
        _write() at stm32_system.cpp:180 0x80096aa  
        _write_r() at 0x800c1ac 
        __sflush_r() at 0x800b7cc   
        _fflush_r() at 0x800b81e    
        __sfvwrite_r() at 0x800ba28 
        _puts_r() at 0x800bcf0  
        smokeTests() at main.cpp:17 0x8001554   
        main() at main.cpp:37 0x80015a8 

With the debugger I see that len=1 is passed when _write is called.
If I remove the leading \n in the string len is correctly passed with 23.
My toolchain:

STM32CubeIDE 1.15.1
GNU tools for STM32 12.3. rel1
Standards: ISO C++20, ISO C18


Check your printf implementation. Maybe it considers \n an end of the string? Or breaking it into multiple writes?

@ChrisF, Post calling code to _write().  In particular, post how len is determined.

stdout is line buffered by default. You are seeing _write call with len=1, and that is expected. But you should then also see the next call with len=23. Please check if this next call happens or not. If not then maybe explicit fflush(stdout) would help - altough it should've worked without it; or alternatively you might want to consider disabling stdout buffering altogether? And if it does happen then _write is suspect - altough it looks fine on first glance.
One small nitpick - BITS_PER_CHARACTER  should be 10, you forgot start bit. Doesn't really matter with *10 margin of course.

On further pondering I think I understand why is it not working. The first line to be output is just "\n", single character. The timeout value for that is 0.7 ms, so it gets chopped to 0 for the HAL timeout value. So I think maybe HAL_UART_Transmit immediately fails with the timeout error, that error gets propagated to C library and stdout gets flagged as erred, so subsequent writes to it fail immediately.

@EugeneSh. Yes this is what I also was considering, but how can I check the implementation? The only thing I see is the header file "stdio.h" but the implementation is provided as object file I guess.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Unfortunately I do not have access to the calling code this is implemented in newlib I gues which is provided by the arm-none-eabi toolchain. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

@AndreyTurkin Yes this is it - great that you found the cause! Indeed, the first call of _write is done only for the leading \n but _write then returns with HAL_TIMEOUT.
What I tried now:

Set the timeout to 99999
then the first call of _write is done with len=1, and it returns with OK
and the next call is done with len=23 and everything is printed as expected

So, as you assumed, _write is called twice for this string.
Would you mind providing this as an answer?
And thanks for the hint with the BITS_PER_CHARACTER, will update my question.
Chris

I added this fix to prevent a zero timeout:
if (timeout_ms < 1) { timeout_ms = 1u; }

There is a subtle bug in _write implementation. The timeout_ms value for a single-character string turns out to be 0. HAL_UART_Transmit with 0 timeout fails with HAL_TIMEOUT immediately after initiating a transmission; that error gets promoted upwards into libc which flags stdout as erred. Therefore, libc wouldn't even try to write anything anymore until that error is manually cleared, thus the rest of the string never gets sent.
